# What should we do with [inverse-cdf] and [quantiles]?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have two closely related tags [inverse-cdf](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inverse-cdf) (18) and [quantiles](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantiles) (334). Maybe instead we should have something like `[quantile-function]` synonym to `[inverse-cdf]` and `[quantiles-empirical]` for all the other questions? Or maybe we should rather make the two tags synonyms?

Comment: What's the problem with having [quantile-function] and [quantiles]?

Comment: @amoeba there is no problem at all, I'm just asking if we can make it less ambiguous and avoid spreading the questions between the tags.

Comment: To me [quantiles] sounds sufficiently different from [quantile-function] that I don't see much ambiguity.

Comment: However, there are a couple of dozens of questions that one could move from [quantiles] to [quantile-function] if we create it. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bquantiles%5d%20%22quantile%20function%22%20is%3aquestion.

Comment: @amoeba most of them mention the "`quantile()` function" from base R so there is probably much less Q's to migrate.

Comment: Even better.$\:$

Comment: @amoeba I created `[quantile-function]` tag and suggested it as a synonym to `[inverse-cdf]`.

Comment: Cool. Unfortunately, there are very few users who would be able to upvote (https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/inverse-cdf/topusers), so we would need one of the mods to approve this synonym.

Comment: I'd say `[quantile-function]` is the same as `[inverse-cdf]` but `[quantiles]` is not a function

Comment: @Glen_b that's the case, but among Q's tagged as `[quantiles]` it becomes blurry... Btw, as far as I can remember you're a mod and you could approve the tag synonym described above?

Comment: @Tim I'd want to see some consensus or at least allow a chance for people to voice disagreement with it first. Just because I think it doesn't mean it should happen. If some questions tagged as `[quantiles]` should be tagged as something else, that would seem to be an argument for changing the tags on those questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize the comments:

1. Make [quantile-function] a synonym of [inverse-cdf]. You can ping @Xian and ask him to vote, but apart from that there are no eligible voters, so we would need a moderator to approve.
2. Check if some threads in [quantiles] need to be retagged into [quantile-function]. Going through [this search with 22 results](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bquantiles%5d%20%22quantile%20function%22%20is%3aquestion) should probably be enough. I see some questions like [Does a univariate random variable's mean always equal the integral of its quantile function?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18438) - definitely a candidate for retagging.

   **Update:** I retagged a couple.

Comment: I re-tagged one more and the rest of the 22 Q's seem to be fine and not need re-tagging.

Comment: @Tim, I wrote about it in chat and whuber accepted the pending synonym. Case closed.